# disable swipe gesture for iCarousel

Tags: ios, swipe-gesture, icarousel

I am using iCarousel to display an array of images and I want to disable the swipe gesture. I did not find that in the documentation. not sure if this is doable or not

Comment: so are you want to programatically change the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the swipe gesture then I think are you want to do something like programatically change the image.

For very simply disable the user interaction of carousel.

If you using storyboard then simple remove checkmark of `User Inreaction Enabled`

[image]

If you use by code then following code to disable the `User Inreaction Enabled`

```
yourcarousel.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
```

May this help lot to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

@Junchao GU If you are Using

> https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

They are using Tap gesture and pan gesture
You have to Comment

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan:)];
panGesture.delegate = (id <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
[_contentView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

//add tap gesture recogniser
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:)];
tapGesture.delegate = (id <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
[_contentView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

in iCarousel.m File

I hope this will help you

Comment: but does not this block of code disable the autoscroll effect that I want?

Comment: okay. pretty sure this will work but changing the source code directly does not sound a good idea to me though. but thanks :)

Comment: Many times i changed source code to make it compatible with my app . Always take Backup of main Source code and then do changes in it.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad idea to change source code of iCarousel. I think it's better to do next:

```
carouselView.contentView.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
```

Hope it helps to someone